# Uknown Column new in FIELD LIST Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql

I have the  following trigger which is supposed to insert on a trigger table after insert. I keep on getting the following error : Unknown Column Field in List

Below is my trigger :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trgr_client_statement_report`;CREATE DEFINER=`uniquelo`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trgr_client_statement_report` AFTER INSERT ON `statement` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO trgr_statement
   ( `amnt_cr`, `amnt_dr`, `approved`,  `clnt_id`,`date_added`,`days`, `description`,
   `discount`,
   `id_2`,
    `invoiced`,
    `invoice_no`,
   `job_card_id`,
   `payment_date`,
   `payment_status`,
   `pymnt_code`,
   `pymnt_mthd`,
   `qty`,
   `rcpt_no`,
   `status`)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.`amnt_cr`,NEW.`amnt_dr`,NEW.`approved`,NEW.`clnt_id`,NEW.`date_added`,NEW.`days`,NEW.`description`,NEW.`discount`,NEW.`id`,NEW.`invoiced`,NEW.`invoice_no`,NEW.`job_card_id`,NEW,`payment_date`,NEW.`payment_status`,NEW.`pymnt_code`,NEW.`pymnt_mthd`,NEW.`qty`,NEW.`rcpt_no`,NEW.`status`)
```

Comment: So, probably one of the columns in that field list doesn't exist in the table. Let me check for you which one.. Oh wait, aww, there is no database structure mentioned.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have `payment_date`, but `pymnt_code`? Wouldn't it be much easier to just have the full name? You're less likely to make mistakes and it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Syntax error in fieldlist. You must use NEW.field not NEW,field : **NEW,`payment_date`**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trgr_client_statement_report`;

CREATE DEFINER=`uniquelo`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trgr_client_statement_report` AFTER INSERT ON `STATEMENT` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO trgr_statement
   ( `amnt_cr`, `amnt_dr`, `approved`,  `clnt_id`,`date_added`,`days`, `description`,
   `discount`,
   `id_2`,
    `invoiced`,
    `invoice_no`,
   `job_card_id`,
   `payment_date`,
   `payment_status`,
   `pymnt_code`,
   `pymnt_mthd`,
   `qty`,
   `rcpt_no`,
   `status`)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.`amnt_cr`,NEW.`amnt_dr`,NEW.`approved`,NEW.`clnt_id`,NEW.`date_added`,NEW.`days`,NEW.`description`,NEW.`discount`,NEW.`id`,NEW.`invoiced`,NEW.`invoice_no`,NEW.`job_card_id`,NEW.`payment_date`,NEW.`payment_status`,NEW.`pymnt_code`,NEW.`pymnt_mthd`,NEW.`qty`,NEW.`rcpt_no`,NEW.`status`)
```